# Cannot get minimax function to work for tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

```
const grabEmptySquares = (array) => {
  var emptyGameSquares = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (!array[i]) emptyGameSquares.push(i);
  }
  return emptyGameSquares;
};

function findBestMove(board) {
  var bestMove = {
    index: null,
    evaluation: null,
  };
  var availableMoves = grabEmptySquares(board);
  availableMoves.forEach((move) => {
    const simulGameboard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));
    simulGameboard[move] = "o";
    const evaluation = minimax(simulGameboard, 1, false);
    const moveDetails = {
      index: move,
      evaluation: evaluation,
    };
    console.log(moveDetails)

    if (evaluation > bestMove.evaluation || bestMove.evaluation === null) {
      bestMove.index = move;
      bestMove.evaluation = evaluation;
    }
  });

  return bestMove.index;
}

function evaluate(board, isMaximizingPlayer, depth) {
  var gameStatus = isGameOver(board);
  if (gameStatus[0] != true) return;
  if (gameStatus[1] === "win")
    return isMaximizingPlayer ? +10 - depth : -10 + depth;
  if (gameStatus[1] === "tie") return 0;
}

function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizingPlayer) {
  var gameStatus = isGameOver(board);
  if (gameStatus[0] == true) {
    const evaluation = evaluate(board, !isMaximizingPlayer, depth);
    return evaluation;
  }

  var simulGameboard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));
  var availableMoves = grabEmptySquares(simulGameboard);

  if (isMaximizingPlayer) {
    bestVal = -Infinity;
    availableMoves.forEach((move) => {
      depth % 2 === 0
        ? (simulGameboard[move] = "o")
        : (simulGameboard[move] = "x");
      value = minimax(simulGameboard, depth + 1, false);
      bestVal = Math.max(bestVal, value);

      const moveDetails = {
        index: move,
        evaluation: bestVal,
        depth: depth,
      };
      console.log(moveDetails);
    });
    return bestVal;
  } else {
    bestVal = Infinity;
    availableMoves.forEach((move) => {
      depth % 2 === 0
        ? (simulGameboard[move] = "o")
        : (simulGameboard[move] = "x");

      value = minimax(simulGameboard, depth + 1, true);
      bestVal = Math.min(bestVal, value);

      const moveDetails = {
        index: move,
        evaluation: bestVal,
        depth: depth,
      };
      console.log(moveDetails);
    });
    return bestVal;
  }
}

function isGameOver(array) {
  var gameOver = false;
  if (
    (array[0] && array[0] === array[1] && array[0] === array[2]) ||
    (array[3] && array[3] === array[4] && array[3] === array[5]) ||
    (array[6] && array[6] === array[7] && array[6] === array[8])
  ) {
    return (gameOver = [true, "win"]);
  }
  if (
    (array[0] && array[0] === array[4] && array[0] === array[8]) ||
    (array[2] && array[2] === array[4] && array[2] === array[6])
  ) {
    return (gameOver = [true, "win"]);
  }
  if (
    (array[1] && array[1] === array[4] && array[4] === array[7]) ||
    (array[0] && array[0] === array[3] && array[3] === array[6]) ||
    (array[2] && array[2] === array[5] && array[5] === array[8])
  ) {
    return (gameOver = [true, "win"]);
  }
  if ([...array].every((index) => index)) {
    return (gameOver = [true, "tie"]);
  }
  return (gameOver = [false, null]);
}
```

I followed https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/ for direction, and as far as I can see, the logic is the same.

Still, my code doesn't come up with the correct moves. The evaluation my minimiax function gives to each move is wrong. And it is sooo wrong I cannot even begin to figure out where the code is off. Please help. I've spent the last two weeks working on this.

Ex:

```
var gameboard = [ null, "o", null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null ]

If I run findBestMove(gameboard), the expected output should be

bestMove = {index: 5,
            evaluation: 0}

What I get instead is 

bestMove = {index: 1,
            evaluation: -8}.

In fact, every single move has the same evaluation.
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by wrong, by providing examples of input and expected output.

Comment: @DeanOC Ok just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the easist code to read, but AFAICT the `minimax` function copies the game board state *once* and then loops through possible moves with `availableMoves.forEach`.  This means that when evaluating each possible move, it acts as if each previously considered move *had been made*.  Move the copy inside the forEach and things should make somewhat more sense.

You already have this in the `findBestMove` function.  I'd strongly suggest unifying `findBestMove` and `minimax` (and the sides of the `isMaximizingPlayer` branch inside `minimax`).  Having very similar code in multiple places makes it hard to remember where you have and haven't fixed things.

I'd also suggest replacing the `isMaximizingPlayer` and `depth%2` logic with a `player` variable that can be either "x" or "o", and multiplying goodness scores by -1 as needed.  It'll be easier to keep track of.

Comment: Holy shit dude thank you so much. Took some time to figure out how to do everything but it finally works. Dunno what the main issue is still but simplifying the code and fixing the board state made it run. Thanks!!